# What is the impact of increase in no of column families of cassandra on heap utilization?

Tags: performance, jvm, cassandra

We are using cassandra-1.1.

For some optimization purpose we decide to increase no of column families in our keyspace.

Will it have any impact on heap utilization?

Is there any possibilities that Cassandra would run out of memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Cassandra Wiki, the heap size consumed 'per node' is defined as:
**memtable_throughput_in_mb * 3 * number of hot CFs + 1G + internal caches**
(ref: [MemtableThresholds](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableThresholds))

So to answer the first question:
*Will it have any impact on heap utilization?*
Yes.

Regarding q2, I strongly believe there is no possibility of OOM with latest versions.  As you mentioned version 1.1 of Cassandra, the per-CF config memtable_throughput_in_mb is replaced by a global memory configuration -  memtable_total_space_in_mb.  This config is equivalent to - memtable_throughput_in_mb * number of hot CFs, in the formula mentioned above.  This ensures that the JVM heap size does not scale with number of CFs and is always guarded by a global config.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Cassandra allocate a minimum of 1MB on the heap for each column family, so you can treat that as the lower bound for heap consumption.  Bloom filters also take up heap space in a way that doesn't necessarily depend on how much you use the column family.

Are you talking about going from 5 to 10 column families? Or 10 to 1000? You certainly *can* run out of heap space with 10 or 1000 column families, it just depends a lot on the rate at which you're inserting data.