# What are the demerits of having an ever increasing number of tables in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I want to tracks events. I can safely assume that total number of unique events would grow but not at a fast rate, but the the incoming stream of events would be lightening fast. So, yes I have a write intensive job at hand. Would it be a bad practise, to create an altogether separate table when I receive a brand new unique event and keep logging who did that event and when in that table?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151498/what-is-the-impact-of-increase-in-no-of-column-families-of-cassandra-on-heap-uti

Answer (score 1):

Having more than a few hundred tables is not recommended. Schema updates are slow when you have a lot of tables. Update time basically becomes linear. Managing a large number of tables also requires good operations/automation/change tracking practices.