# Cassandra impact of increasing number of column families

Tags: java, cassandra, cqlsh, cassandra-2.1

There is a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151498/what-is-the-impact-of-increase-in-no-of-column-families-of-cassandra-on-heap-uti). However the answer relates to an older version of cassandra.

I am using **dsc-cassandra-2.1.10**.
Right now we have about 40 column families. We expect to break each of these down into smaller tables/finer categories, which will increase the table count to about 400 column families.

I am mainly concerned about **memtable** memory requirement and impact on **minor compactions**.

And then what general effect will these have on the nodes themselves. I expect the JVM memory requirement to increase. But don't know how aggressive the effect will be as a result of adding more column families

Any other repercussions of having this many column families will also be helpful. None of the existing answers seem to be regarding recent versions.

Additional Info: Of the 400 the column families, 15 will have high frequency updates to the same set of rows (but different partition keys).

About 15 will have updates and inserts every minute. About 7000 partition keys will get updated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

DataStax urges caution >=200 tables

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/planningAntiPatterns.html#planningAntiPatterns__AntiPatTooManyTables

```
Warning threshold: 200 tables. The cluster may run smoothly above this threshold, but once your database reaches the warning threshold, it's time to start monitoring and planning a re-architecture. If possible, remove unused and underutilized tables.

Failure threshold: 500 tables. On a cluster that has exceeded 500 tables, expect problems and errors, including (but not limited) issues related to high memory usage and compactions.
```